# What are the benefits of using SQL 'WHERE' over selecting through PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I'm trying to understand the benefits of using SQL's `where` clause over selecting through PHP (or vice-versa) What makes one more preferable than the other or does it simply not matter? This is regarding both performance, security and overall in general programming.

**Example:**

Why should I use:

`$sql = SELECT * FROM database WHERE id='1'`

over:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM database";
foreach ($db->query($sql) as $row) {
    if ($row['id'] === $id) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Imagine if you have millions of rows returned, its easier to get just one, instead of the entire dataset.

Comment: And just for your info `from table` not `from database`

Comment: which RDBMS is used here, mysql or sql-server? they're different

Comment: SQL and PHP are two different animals here and PHP can't do this (query) alone. Your title and the question wasn't properly explained.

Comment: *"This is regarding ... security"* - Seems that nobody answered that part. This makes the question too broad.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Then how come the people who answered it seemed to understand it? If you import the database you can then use PHP to select it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SELECT` will perform the filtering in the database itself whereas to do the filtering in `php` the app has to transfer all the data over the network to php.

Imagine the `CPU` usage and network traffic if you need to filter out just one row from 1 million rows.

Answer (score 4):

You are unnecessarily bringing all the data from DB Server to middletier and looping those data in middle tier, whereas in db querying it uses appropriate indexes and retrieve your required records faster